# How to queue up work for requests and only perform work once for the same

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an API where my endpoint accepts an ID and then performs a heavy operation to compose the result (generates a PDF).

It's possible that I will get the same request for the same resource multiple times in a short timeframe, so I'd like some sort of work queue that keeps track of IDs, and the first request would initiate the actual work and the following requests would (first check if it's already in the pipeline then) simply wait until the work is done and return the same result.

First I thought maybe a `ConcurrentDictionary` would be useful, but I don't know how to handle the *wait until the work is done* part. I also looked at `ObservableCollection`, but I'm not sure about its safety (without putting too much effort into making it safe manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use a normal dictionary with a lock around it and `Task`'s inside, which complete when the result for the work item has been calculated.

That means doing each part of work is represented as a `Task<WorkResult>`.

If a new request comes in you can do something like:

```
lock (currentWork)
{
  Task<WorkResult> workItem = null;
  if (currentWork.TryGetResult(workId, out workItem))
  {
    // Work is already in progress. Reuse that work item
    return workItem; // The caller can await that
  }

  // Create a new workItem
  workItem = FunctionThatStartsWork(); // Could also be a Task.Run(...) thing
  // Store it in the map
  currentWork[workId] = workItem;

  // Return it to the caller so that he can await it
  return workItem;
}
```

Now there's a question left on who removes the item from the dictionary. One approach could be to attach a continuation on creation of the work task that will remove it from the map once it's finished.

```
workItem.ContinueWith(wi => {
  lock (currentWork) {
    currentWork.Remove(workId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah so basically I'm storing tasks in a dictionary, and if an ID is not yet present, I add the `Task` to it, while in subsequent requests for the same ID, I take out the task and `await` them?

Comment: yes, that's it. You could also do a blocking `.Wait()` or `.Result` on them, but I guess you have async/await available and would prefer not to block the whole thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to scale this I would recommend an alternative architecture using a message queue (such as RabbitMQ). Your API will simply publish the messages to the queue and then you could have a Windows Service that will consume the messages and process them. The 2 applications could of course share a common data store in order to synchronize the information.